# Reversing order of second column only in for a 2x2 ND-Array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Right now I have a 2x2 ND-array, namely `np.array([[93,  95], [84, 100], [99,  87]])`. I would like to reverse the second column of the array into, such that I get: `np.array([[93,  87], [84, 100], [99,  95]])`.

I tried the following code:

```
grades = np.array([[93,  95], [84, 100], [99,  87]])
print(grades[::-1,:])
```

However, the result I get is

```
[[ 99  87]
 [ 84 100]
 [ 93  95]]
```

I understand that this is because I am reversing all of the entries in the 1-axis, which is why the entries in the first column is also reversed. So what code can I write to get:

```
[[ 93  87]
 [ 84 100]
 [ 99  95]]
```

Comment: Select the column you want to reverse, apply the `::-1`, and then copy that back.  Do the the most obvious thing, rather than seek something magical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.flip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) function to reverse the order of values in specific column(s), though it's more suitable for a more extended/general cases:

```
grades = np.array([[93,  95], [84, 100], [99,  87], [99, 83]])
grades[:, -1] = np.flip(grades[:, -1])
print(grades)
```

Or just use the reversed order of rows:

```
grades[:, -1] = grades[::-1, -1]
```

---

```
[[ 93  83]
 [ 84  87]
 [ 99 100]
 [ 99  95]]
```

Comment: Can there be a more general solution to the problem? For example instead of a 3x2 array, I have a 4x2 array such as `[[93,  95], [84, 100], [99,  87],[99,83]]` and want to change it into `[[93,  83], [84, 87], [99,  100],[99,95]]`

Comment: @Willow, update your initial question with extended requirement